# bypass nodejs express-http-proxy from some requests

Tags: node.js, http-proxy

I have an express-http-proxy used to redirect the request to another server. I would like to redirect some requests only, here below are the redirected requests code;

```
app.use('/api', proxy('abc.com', {
// preserveHostHdr: true,
https: isHttps,
proxyReqPathResolver: function (req) {
    return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
}}));
```

I tried

```
app.use('/', proxy('abc.com', {
// preserveHostHdr: true,
https: isHttps,
proxyReqPathResolver: function (req) {
    return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
}}));
```

after the first block to bypass any other requests but I found out that proxy keeps forwarding any request. is there a way to bypass the proxy and call some HTML files on the same host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as bellow;
I must first declare a static path to express and all of the path content will be public. after that ı did the redirection.

```
app.use('/api', proxy('abc.com', {
        // preserveHostHdr: true,
        https: isHttps,
            proxyReqPathResolver: function (req) {
            return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
        }
    }));

app.use(express.static("./web"));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
         res.sendFile(require('path').join(__dirname, ''));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy

filter (supports Promises)
The filter option can be used to limit what requests are proxied. Return true to continue to execute proxy; return false-y to skip proxy for this request.

```
app.use('/proxy', proxy('www.google.com', {
  filter: function(req, res) {
     return req.url === 'http://www.urltobeproxied.com';
  }
}));
```

also you can intercept to return data of your choice

```
app.use('/proxy', proxy('www.google.com', {
  userResDecorator: function(proxyRes, proxyResData, userReq, userRes) {
    data = JSON.parse(proxyResData.toString('utf8'));
    data.newProperty = 'exciting data';
    return JSON.stringify(data);
  }
}));
```

Comment: actually, ı saw the filters but the point is here (I think). proxy do forward needed requests to xyz.com/api but when a normal request received like abc.com/index.html the filter returns false and I don't know why it's forward again to xyz.com/index . I think we start to have a loop.app.use('/', proxy(endPoint, {
    // preserveHostHdr: true,
    https: isHttps,
    filter: function(req, res) {
        return require('url').parse(req.url).path !== '/index.html';
     },
    proxyReqPathResolver: function (req) {
        return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
    }
}));

Comment: if the filter return false , it should not forward the request to proxy

Return true to continue to execute proxy; return false-y to skip proxy for this request.

Comment: thank you for your help. I found out the solution. I had no static folder represented on express!